# How to fill up with numbers a $3 \times 3$ square with almost no information given?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

The problem is as follows:

Each of the blank square must be filled using a positive number such the product of the numbers in each column and each row to be equal to $1$. Also the product of the four numbers which occupy the $2 \times 2$ square must be 2. Find the sum of the digits of the number to be written in the center square painted with color.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&4\\
2.&6\\
3.&5\\
4.&7\\
\end{array}$

I'm stuck with this problem at the very beginning as I'm not sure if there exists some sort of methodology or approach that can be used. There is also the fact that I don't know what's meant by the phrase "the four numbers which occupy the $2 \times 2$ square must be 2". I believe that what it was intended to be asked is that there are four zones in the $3 \times 3$ square which can be $2 \times 2$, two in the upper portion of the square and the other two in the lower portion, but still I'm not sure about this. Can somebody with experience solving these kind of riddles help me?. I'd appreciate if there could be some sort of logic that can be explained with many details as possible so I can understand what's going on. Typically I would try to offer some attempt into solving this, but I really have no idea on what to do other than just guessing.

Comment: Are the numbers integers or real numbers? If the numbers are only integers ,then the only way to get the product equal to 1 would be when all numbers are equal to 1

Comment: They are integers.

Comment: Then, as @The points out, the problem is pretty silly. For the product of a bunch of positive integers to be one, each of the integers must be one

Comment: If an answer was found, as the OP I would really appreciate you can post what did you do to get to that answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, I don't know why you meant the problem is silly?. Could it be that the person who posed this made it too simple?. Or am I overlooking something?. I'm slow with these riddles. :(

Comment: The problem "silly" because it is a literal contradiction: if the product of positive integers must be 1, then these integers must be 1, no other option, so the product of some other subset cannot be 2

Comment: @Servaes The OP says **integer positive numbers**. So, they can't be fractions.

Comment: I think you have to go back to wherever you got this problem, make sure you have quoted it exactly correctly, and then let them know the problem is busted.

Comment: Anything to say, Chris? Two answers, numerous comments, no reaction from you.

Comment: Are you still here, Chris?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I'm deeply sorry I did not meant to abandon this question. I had to take an exam and I could not came back until today to review all the feedback. I'm voting to reopen this question.

Comment: You can (and should) engage with what others have contributed even while the question is closed, Chris.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I tried to understand the intended purpose of the one who posed this question. Some inputs say it is a contradiction but the only answer which has come up with a solution doesn't really help me much. I left a comment under the existing answer but I'm unsure if the one who wrote that may reply given the elapsed time.

Comment: The user who posted that answer has given a "reply" by deleting the answer. I think you should read through the inputs that say it's a contradiction and think about them until you come to accept that conclusion or until you find a way out of it.

Comment: To repeat what others have pointed out to you: the only way a product of positive integers can be $1$ is for each of the integers to be $1$. You refer to "the $2\times2$ square", but it's unclear what you mean by this. And whatever you mean by this, the product of the four numbers occupying that square can't be $2$, as each of the four numbers has to be $1$. So the problem is a nonsense as stated, and there's really nothing anyone can do for you under the circumstances.

Comment: Gone again, Chris?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry. I haven't gone. I tried to revisit and retry doing this problem by my own. Upon inspecting the original source I'm still perplexed by the meaning of $2\times 2$ square. I guess that the intended purpose is to  *divide* the whole magic square into 4 subections of $2 \times 2$ squares starting from the top left and ending in the bottom right, hence becoming four sectors.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have read the problem again from the original source and I noticed that it did not mentioned anything about *integers*, the problem only mentioned positive numbers. So it can be a real number (as with integers do generate a contradiction). But if this is the case what would be the way to solve this problem?.

Comment: And you were so insistent that you had read the problem carefully and copied it perfectly and it had to be integers. Jeez. Anyway, the way to solve the problem is the way Inactive solved it for you when you first posted it two weeks ago.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm sorry I thought that I copied it as it was in the source. But when I compared with what was written then I noticed that the word *integer* was not in the original problem. As I was in a rush I did added this part as similar problems before this had that word included. But again, I tried to do it by my own and my guess is it can be $4$?. But I'm not sure to prove that.

Comment: Inactive got the middle number to be $16$, which has digit sum $7$, which is alternative $\#4$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The answer is no longer visible which makes it difficult for me to understand how did he got to that number. I wish to have access to that answer. Can it be reverted?. As it stands now, no new answers can be added to a closed question.

Comment: You have only yourself to blame for the closure of the question, and for not taking more careful note of the answer before its owner deleted it (and for leading the owner to delete it by insisting the answer was wrong). I voted to undelete that answer, but no one has joined me yet. Anyway, it was just a lot of arithmetic, I'm sure you can reproduce it. The user did assume that each of the four $2\times2$ squares had product $2$. After that, it's just a lot of number-chasing. Go for it!

Comment: @GerryMyerson Okay. I appreciate your help. If I had commented earlier probably he would had not deleted his answer. However trying to reproduce with what one had solved reverts me back to the original problem which is what method can be used as it turns out that I have to do different trials.

Answer (score 1):

> Each of the blank square must be filled using an integer positive number such the product of the numbers in each column and each row to be equal to $1$.

Trivially, this means that all entries are $1$. But at the same time

> Also the product of the four numbers which occupy the $2 \times 2$ square must be 2.

This is a contradiction. So if you've stated the problem correctly, it is wrong.

Comment: I revised this problem and in the original source it didn't mention anything about the numbers being integers. So I assume it can allow reals, hence fractions. Would this ease or make this problem not be a contradiction?. Can you help me with that?